# how to take image from physical path(local disc)

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.FileName);
HttpPostedFile pf = FileUpload.PostedFile;
System.Drawing.Image img2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(pf.InputStream);

System.Drawing.Image bmp2 = img2.GetThumbnailImage(200, 210, null, IntPtr.Zero);

Imagename = objUser.UserID + filename;
Imagepath = "D:\\Shopy_Web_21-6-12\\Shopy\\Images" + Imagename;
bmp2.Save(Path.Combine(@"D:\Shopy_Web_21-6-12\Shopy\Images", Imagename));
```

I've converted the file upload in to two thumbnails and saved them locally, but now I need retrieve the image to display it on the user's profile. How can I get the image to display from where I've stored it?

Comment: Create an ashx that will render the file (See [this link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx))

Comment: is there possible to take the image without ashx????

Comment: @karthik What do you mean by "I need to get image from that physical path"..?

Comment: @karthik: You can direct-link tot he file assuming the files are within the website's directory and the name of the file is stored some place where you can retrieve and reference it.

Comment: i got image from fileupload and converted into thumbanail and then stored in the above physical path ..now i want to take image from that disc(D) and show it in my web page?? how to do this friend..guide me

Comment: Don't you know where the image are on your disk and place them inside an img anchor ?

Comment: I've suggested that as well but it seems like the author is of the kind "if you don't give me exact lines of code don't bother"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a virtual path in your application say: `..Images/` and save your images in that folder.

and after that use the below one to fetch the image URL:

```
string str = Server.MapPath("Images/" + Filename);
```

Now you will get the url to your image that can be displayed directly.

Comment: string FileToShow = Server.MapPath(Imagepath);;
                        Img_Show.ImageUrl = FileToShow;  its not working friend

Comment: @Karthik - You can't map your `ImagePath` as it is not a virutal reference.  Look more closely at this answer and follow ALL the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Link your images folder (`...\Shopy\Images`) to a virtual folder under your app so then you can link to them within `<img>` elements.